# Setting up dir. structure with dsss

Tags: d, dsss

I'm trying to setup directoy structure with dsss:

```
./proj  -- project files

./src   -- source
./dev   -- dev files, test files
./lib   -- source for libraries used

./res   -- resource files
./doc   -- documentation

./bin   -- binary files
./obj   -- object files
```

Not properly working `dsss.conf` in the `./proj` directory.

```
name=SomeProject

srcdir+=../src # this doesn't work

[../lib/sqlite3-d]
type=subdir

# Test files
[../dev/sqlite-test.d]
target=../bin/test-sqlite

# Program
[../src/main.d]
target=../bin/main
```

Any idea where to get more information on how to setup such structure more nicely. I'm unable to find the proper location to put the folder structure information.

The main thing i'm trying to accomplish is to keep files generated by dsss only in `./obj` and `./bin` directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working with using `rebuild` and `Makefile`:

This the `Makefile`:

```
CMD = rebuild $< -Isrc -Idev -oqobj -ofbin/$@

SOURCES = src/srcfile1.d src/srcfile2.d

all: main test

main: src/main.d $(SOURCES)
    $(CMD)

test: dev/test.d $(SOURCES)
    $(CMD)

cleanall: clean
clean:
    rm -f bin/main
    rm -f bin/test
    rm -f obj/*
```